# Getting error _OBJC_CLASS_$_AdMobView while compiling in iPhone SDK 4

Tags: iphone, admob

I implemented Admob in my application previously in 3.x versions of SDk there i used libAdMobDevice3_0.a frame work. But now i am using 4.o version when i am compiling i am getting the compilation error **_OBJC_CLASS_$_AdMobView** can any one give me the link from where i can download **Admob 4**

Thank You
Kiran Manthena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your AdMob account you will get the latest version of AdMob.